# Prestashop 1.6 Automatically adding a customer to a group upon virtual product purchase

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Using Prestashop 1.6 is there a way to automatically add a customer to a group when they purchase a virtual product?

Example: Virtual product is a membership. When they buy the product, I want them to be assigned to the Members group.

One way I was thinking of achieving this was to do the following:
Can the virtual product link that the customer receives in the email be a link to a PHP page that I create? I was thinking of writing a PHP page with an activate membership button that would insert them into the proper group via MySQL code.

I could not find a module to do this. I would like to avoid creating a module because then I would have to study module creation and I was hoping for an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

The highly recomended solution is a custom module that will assign the user when the payment is confirmed. It can be done with changes to the core file, but this is the worst solution, since after the next upgrade of PrestaShop those changes will be overriden. Module creation is not so hard, you just need to implement the hook "actionOrderStatusUpdate" and asign the order customer to previously selected customer group from the module configure page.